# How to refactor XSL files before merge?

Tags: xslt, refactoring

I have a rather big XSL file with lots of templates. Now I need to append to it the templates from another XSL file. Unfortunately, some template names used there are the same as the template names in the first file. So if I just copy and paste them the whole XSL gets broken.

What is the simplest way of refactoring the second XSL file before appending it? Can I put its templates into a different namespace or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing new code, you can put the template names in a namespace.

If the code already exists, you can write a new transformation that processes an XSLT transformation and replaces any

```
/*/xsl:template/@name
```

with its value concatenated with `'_', $SomeSuffix`, where `$SomeSuffix` is a global/external parameter.

You could use the same process to replace the names of the tepmplates with ones that are in  a namespace, which is given as a parameter.

Comment: Huh, refactoring XSL with XSL. Seems nice! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @svz, You are welcome -- please, let me know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: @DimitreNovatcev, worked like a charm, though I had to rename `call-template` nodes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have named templates (i.e. `template name="foo"`) then yes, use namespaces to distinguish them i.e. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:l1="http://example.com/l1" version="1.0"><xsl:template name="l1:foo">...</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`.